# Adobe Air - Sign app for BlackBerry

Tags: air, blackberry-playbook, sign, blackberry-10

I'm building a simple game with Flash CS5 and Adobe Air 2.5. 
I would like to publish it on the BlackBerry App World.

I published an .apk and tried to pack it with the [BlackBerry online tool](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/) but I'm getting this compatibility error:

> ImpactTypeReason 5 / native-code / armeabi-v7a

What is **armeabi-v7a**?

Thank you, Uli

Answer (score 1):

Why do you try to convert your Android .apk file?

With Flash CS5 you can [publish for Blackberry](https://developer.blackberry.com/air/) (as a .bar file).

Comment: Sounds great but I can't find that option. Can you please explain it a little more? (If I open my game .fla file in Flash CS5 I can't find the .bar option under publish settings)

Comment: Rebuild you Flash project with the blackberry tools: https://developer.blackberry.com/air/

Comment: Publishing AIR app for Blacberry is very easy: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-blackberry.html